# Can I use a local Eclipse with my microclimate running on IBM Cloud Private?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, microclimate

I know I can point Eclipse at a local workspace running in a local microclimate.

But is there a way to integrate my local Eclipse ID with microclimate hosted in ICP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't have a way to use local Eclipse to work with resources in microclimate running in ICP yet. You have to use the editor that comes with Micoclimate to edit it.  I have created a story to keep track on it so that we can put it into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Elson - much appreciated. Hope that story is prioritised for delivery.